# How to show New Products in custom woocommerce shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode, add-filter

I want edit woocommerce products shortcode to show only **products without price**;
When create new product, it doesn't have price value (not empty, not null).
How can I filter new products without price?

I use **'value'   => ''** but my shortcode don't show new products.
When I set price for new products and then remove it, this product show in my shortcode.
my shortcode is: **[products class="bp-noprice"]**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'biapin_filter_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 10, 3 );

function biapin_filter_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ) {
    if ( $atts['class'] == 'bp-noprice' ) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = array (
            array(
                'key'     => '_price',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ),
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Comment: Is this for simple products only, or including variable products?

Comment: I tested this function for simple products.

Answer (score 0):

This will update the shortcode to ONLY show simple products with no price.  A price of 0.00 is when something had a price, but it was removed.  A price that `NOT EXISTS` is a product that was entered in new, but the price field was left empty.  If you only want the latter, then you can adjust the query and remove the `0` condition.

Note that this query would be a `slow query` with the tax_query option included.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'biapin_filter_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 10, 3 );
function biapin_filter_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ) {
    if ( 'bp-noprice' === $atts['class'] ) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => '_price',
                'value'   => '0',
                'compare' => '=',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_price',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        );
        $query_args['tax_query']  = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'simple' ),
            ),
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```